# gridview control update javascript not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit

I have a simple asp.net gridview control on a page. The control is bound to SQLDataSource. The gridview control is set to enable editing. When I run the page on my development server the editing function works as it should, i.e. you select edit, modify a column the select update and the change is saved. When I put the page on the live server and select edit I get the edit functionality, but the Update link does not work. It would appear the page does not post back as nothing happens when the Update link is selected. The javascript embeded in the update link (Update) appears to be the same as what is embedded in the update on my dev. server. The Cancel link functionality does work.

Any thoughts on why this would not on the production server? I have another page with the same functionality and it works fine. Can't see any differences.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you post some code? That would make it easier to pinpoint any issues.

Comment: Been searching the web and experimenting. The issue is caused by a required field validator that has nothing to do with the gridview and isn't even on the page when posted in this mode. Ran the page in FireFox with Firebug. Got a javascript error "ReferenceError: Sys is not defined ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not definded". Took validator off the page and the error goes away. I am puzzled but will work around the validator.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have permissions to write to your data source.  I just had this same problem and it turned out that in IIS I needed to grant write access to the appropriate folder on the server (my data source was an xml file).